# Express app using firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

Im trying to run an Express app into firebase, i'm following the steps of this official video:

[Node.js apps on Firebase hosting crash course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8&t=296s)

My Express app is actually running on this URL

> http://localhost:5001/my-app/us-central1/app/test

But on the video, the demostration is running on this url

> http://localhost:5000/test

So, i'm really confused about this, i'been made everything as the tutorial shows

this is my code on functions/index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`Well if i'm reading this the app is working`)
})


exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

And this is firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrite":[{
      "source": "/test",
      "function": "app"
    }],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

What i'm doing wrong? if i enter to localhost:5000 i just get the public static index.html, i just want to control the app by myself.

I hope you can give me a little help to get documented, thanks!

Comment: The `firebase.json` maps `/test` to your app, so `localhost:5000/test` should serve the express app.

Comment: That's the logical behavior but isn't working on that way, instead is rendering the public/index.html file

Comment: How are you running the functions locally?

Comment: This is printed by the console:  </br>functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
Warning: You're using Node.js v8.11.2 but Google Cloud Functions onl
6.11.1.
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: public
+  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000

+  functions: app: http://localhost:5001/r-commerce/us-central1/app

Comment: So it looks like your app locally is being server from `localhost:5001/r-commerce/us-central1/app`. What happens if you open that URL.

Comment: If i open that url the app runs right, i deleted index.html from public folder and now console prints this `[hosting] Rewriting /test to local function app` And now the app is running on `localhost:5000/test`. half of the answer, still don't work on deploy

Comment: Delete index.html but conserve 404.html solves the problem, Thanks For your help Frank!

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that Firebase Hosting will serve static content that matches any paths **before** using any rewrites.  If you want to control a path with Cloud Functions, you will have to make sure that there is no static content that matches the path.

For single page apps in particular, it's critical to remove index.html, as that will always be served as static content.